# Error con al buscar datos

Tags: php

```
    if (isset($_POST["verificacion"])) {
        require_once("../bd/conexion02.php");

        $camposis = $_POST["codiSIS"];
        $campodni = $_POST["dniusu"];
 
        $consulta_usu =mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM sis WHERE dniusu='".$campodni."' AND codigosis='".$camposis."'" );
    
        $numeroFilas=mysqli_num_rows($consulta_usu);
        
    if ($numeroFilas!=0) {
        while ($fila=mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta_usu)) {
            $bddniusu=$fila['dniusu'];
            $bdcodiSiS=$fila['codigosis'];
        }
    
    
            if ($camposis == $bdcodiSiS) {
            if ($campodni == $bddniusu) {
                echo "El usuario cuenta con SIS";
            } else {
                echo "El codigo SIS pertenece a otra persona";
            }
        } else {
            echo "El codigo SIS no existe";
        }
    }
    }
```

> Porque $consulta_usu da un valor de 0 cuando en realidad tiene que votar un valor diferente a 0,
> Lo que el sistema hace es que al llenar los campos del formulario codiSIS y dniusu esos debe buscar en la bd y arrojar un resultado

Comment: Si ejecutas la consulta en MySQL qué valor obtienes?

Comment: Edita la pregunta para agregar el código HTML del formulario. Para depurar, antes de realizar la consulta agrega `var_dump($_POST);` para verificar que los datos recibidos son correctos. Luego, como te sugirió @Bicho, ejecuta la consulta directamente en la base de datos (Consola MySQL, PhpMyAdmin, etc.) para ver si devuelve resultados.

Comment: El `$_POST` devuelve las variables pedidas y `$camposis` y `$campodn` tienen las varibles que se pone en el formulario, al no encontrar datos puestos en `$camposis` o `$campodni` no encuentra ningún rows por lo tanto `$numeroFilas` no entra a asignar variables `$bdcodiSiS` y el if da como indefinidos y ya no entra al analizar el segundo if